# How to generate unique Extent report for each Run in specflow and store it

Tags: specflow, extentreports

Currently my code overwrites the extent report for each run.
How to generate unique Extent report for each Run in specflow and store it?

```
var report= new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"c:\report.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define each report where you want, Refer Example:

In method-1 you want your first report, So you may define there.

```
void method1(){
var report= new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"c:\report.html");
}

void method2(){
// You don't want to generate new report for method2 and continue to lof under report1
}

void method3(){
//You wan't to generate new report from method 3, you can define it here with different name
}
```

And like wise, You can have multiple reports. Example of Method may take place with class.

Comment: It is recommended if we have 2 or 3 methods. In a large scale we can't use it.

Comment: I resolved it by giving unique name to each report as below.  var path = @"c:\report.html" ; var report= new ExtentHtmlReporter(path+DateTime.Now.ToString()+".html");

Comment: You can give unique name by multiple way, Date and Time and method name are implied way to define it.

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if you think it has helped you.

Comment: yeah. that's what i stated above, I used DateTime method to resolve it.

Comment: There are multiple ways to represent unique identity. If your problem got solved on provided solution, You may accept it.